# Switching documents in VS2010 with Ctrl-Tab needs return

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

When switching between documents in VS2010 with Ctrl-Tab, the document switch window doesn't disappear until I've pressed tab multiple times to select an entry and then hit return. I'm *sure* that it didn't need the return previously: that the window only stayed up as long as you held down Ctrl and then when released it switched to the currently selected document.  This is really annoying if you want to just hit ctrl-tab quickly to go to the last document.

I do have a few Extensions installed including Productivity Power Tools, Power Commands and VSVim, and I've also installed a couple of tools for investigating accessibility (NVDA, UIA Verifier in the platform SDK), so it's possible that one of these may have somehow changed the options.

So, my questions are:

1. Is the default behaviour of VS2010 that the document switch window only works while the Ctrl key is held down, or is my memory faulty?
2. If the default behaviour is as I remember, how do I get back to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this turned out to be an accessibility setting that was in a half-enabled state. In the Windows Accessibility settings I toggled the state of Sticky Keys a couple of times and now it's working correctly again.

Answer (score 2):

This has just happened to me, and after some googling I found [the solution](http://andyclymer.blogspot.de/2010/02/visual-studio-ctrltab-sticking.html): it was really the magnifier application I ocassionally started by pressing `Win` + `Grey Plus`. Once I have closed it the Visual Studio just worked fine without restart.

Comment: Holy sweet bajoobus. This has dogged me for months.I opened the magnifier application and shut it down again and I have my ctrl tab back again. 

The problem appeared after I installed Dragon Screen Reader and I wasn't able to get the old functionality back. Cheers!

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Windows 10 Professional (just upgraded) however #3 here does: http://tilt.carr.no/Post/12/visual-studio-ide-navigator-stuck

Answer (score 1):

Regarding point 2. 
Go to Tools : Import and Export Settings.  You can then choose to reset the default environment settings again.

Also ensure than it's not an 'add-in' providing functionality different to that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour with VS2012: when the Magnifier application is open (e.g. by pressing Windows logo key‌ + "+" (plus sign)) this behaviour occurs even if the magnification is set to 100%.